# How to make a customized range slider for font-size?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario,in that I have to use the range slider for font size,But  I have a normal slider,I need to display the font-size on tool-tip when it slides.

JS:

```
angular.module('textSizeSlider', [])
  .directive('textSizeSlider', ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="text-size-slider"><span class="small-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: min + unit }">A</span> <input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}" ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}" /> <span class="big-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: max + unit }">A</span></div>',
      scope: {
        min: '@',
        max: '@',
        unit: '@',
        value: '@',
        step: '@'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.textSize = scope.value;
        scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
          $document[0].body.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Here is the plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uzggs7sVA5KCuuHxQ2Yh?p=preview

Expected result must be shown in below figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a span and then move it relative to your range slider by taking the width of the slider and multiplying it by the current value divided by the max.

```
angular.module('textSizeSlider', [])
  .directive('textSizeSlider', ['$document', function ($document) {

    var ctrl = ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.position = 0;
        $scope.updatepointer = () => {
          var input =  $element.find("input");
          var width = input[0].offsetWidth -16; // 16 for offsetting padding
          var ratio = ($scope.textSize - $scope.min) / ($scope.max - $scope.min);
          var position = width * ratio;
          $scope.position = Math.trunc(position); 

        }

    }]

    return {
      controller: ctrl,
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="text-size-slider"><span class="pointer" style="left:{{position}}px;"><span>{{textSize}}</span></span><span class="small-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: min + unit }">A</span> <input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}" ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}" ng-change="updatepointer()" /> <span class="big-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: max + unit }">A</span></div>',
      scope: {
        min: '@',
        max: '@',
        unit: '@',
        value: '@',
        step: '@'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.textSize = scope.value;

        scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
          $document[0].body.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
          scope.updatepointer();
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

I added the css for pointer here:

```
.pointer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius:20px 20px  0 20px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  display:block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position:absolute;
  top: -44px;
  margin-left:8px;

}

.pointer span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin-left:12px;
  margin-top: 14px;


}
```

The working plunker is here:  https://plnkr.co/edit/9bYR1aprS3Xn7YWyB6kj?p=preview

Comment: in the slider,how to change the track color,means intially it will be one color when it slides the color must be changed,it is working fine in firefox and IE.Iam facing issue with chrome,can you please help me in this.

Comment: Take a look at this site for how to style the slider: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/